# Match all combinations of any classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two comma-separated selectors;

```
.class, .foo, .bar

.lorem, .ipsum, .potato
```

I'd like to be able to select any possible combination between these two groups. So it would select elements matching

```
.class.lorem
.class.ipsum
.class.potato
.foo.lorem
.foo.ipsum
.foo.potato
.bar.lorem
.bar.ipsum
.bar.potato
```

How can I achieve this effectively?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select all elements with any class from the first set, and then [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) out the elements which don't have a class from the other set:

```
$('.class, .foo, .bar').filter('.lorem, .ipsum, .potato')
```

Comment: That's so stupidly brilliant it doesn't even make sense. Thank you.

Comment: @EmphramStavanger You're welcome :) If you have a significantly greater number of elements matching the first selector than the second, you may also benefit from switching the order to: `$('.lorem, .ipsum, .potato').filter('.class, .foo, .bar')`